# Xcode 8, Swift 3. Value of type DataService has no member "Sign up"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I am trying to make a Sign in / Sign up screen with Firebase. And i created a swift class for send data to Firebase and i called the class "DataService". I have also Sign in and Sign up classes. In the "DataService" class i cant create more than one function, i am getting error like ***Value of type DataService has no member "Sign up"*** when i am trying to create a sign up function. But the other function works fine. I can have just only one function in this class(DataService).

**DATASERVICE class**

```
  import Foundation
  import Firebase
  import FirebaseAuth
  import FirebaseStorage

let rootRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

class DataService {

static let dataService = DataService()

private var _BASE_REF = rootRef
private var _PHOTO_REF = rootRef.child("photos")

var BASE_REF: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _BASE_REF
}

var PHOTO_REF: FIRDatabaseReference {
    return _PHOTO_REF
}

var storageRef: FIRStorageReference{
    return FIRStorage.storage().reference()
}

var fileUrl: String!



// Share Photo Data

func shareNewPhoto(user: FIRUser, caption: String, data: NSData) {
let filePath = "\(user.uid)/\     (Int(NSDate.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate))"
 let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
    metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
    storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData) { (metadata, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error uploading: /\(error.localizedDescription)")

        }

        // Create a Url for data ( Story Photo)

        self.fileUrl = metadata!.downloadURLs![0].absoluteString
        if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
            let idPhotoRoom = self.BASE_REF.child("PhotoRooms").childByAutoId()
            idPhotoRoom.setValue(["caption": caption, "StoryPhotoUrlFromStorage": self.storageRef.child(metadata!.path!).description, "fileUrl": self.fileUrl])
        }
    }


    // Story Photo (upload and dowload from server)

func fetchDataFromServer(callback:@escaping (StoryPhoto) -> ()) {
    DataService.dataService._PHOTO_REF.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        let photo = StoryPhoto(key: snapshot.key, snapshot: snapshot.value as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
            callback(photo)

        })



       // Sign Up

func signUp(username: String, email: String, password: String, data: NSData) {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        let changeRequest = user?.profileChangeRequest()
        changeRequest?.displayName = username
        changeRequest?.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
        })

        let filePath = "profileimage/\(user!.uid)"
        let metaData = FIRStorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpeg"

        self.storageRef.child(filePath).put(data as Data, metadata: metaData, completion: { (metadata, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
            self .fileUrl = metadata?.downloadURLs![0].absoluteString
            let changeRequestPhoto = user!.profileChangeRequest()
            changeRequestPhoto.photoURL = NSURL(string: self.fileUrl) as URL?
            changeRequestPhoto.commitChanges(completion: { (error) in
                if let error = error {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }else{
                    print("profile uptaded")
                }
            })

            let appDelegate: AppDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appDelegate.Login()

        })


    })
}

}


}

}
```

**Sign Up class**. Here i am getting error like **Value of type DataService has no member "Sign up".**

```
// Register Button

@IBAction func RegisterDidTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let username = usernameTextField.text else {
        return
    }

    var data = NSData()
    data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(profileImage.image!, 0.1)! as NSData

    //Signin up


  Here i am getting Error: (Value of type DataService has no member "sign Up")

    DataService.dataService.signUp(username: username, email: email, password: password, data: data)


 }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that you putting functions inside other functions. Don't do that in this case. Functions that need to be called from other code should be top-level functions of the class, not embedded inside other functions.

And, unrelated, please use proper, standard naming conventions. Method and variable names should start with lowercase letters. Classnames start with uppercase letters.

Comment: But how should i put these functions out of other functions?

Comment: Put them at the same level as the `ShareNewPhoto` function.

Comment: I am still getting same error, its not working. I have no idea what is wrong with this code.

Comment: Update your question with your latest code and clearly indicate what error you are getting and where.